# Oracle SQL Developer Query Connect as Other User

Tags: sql, oracle

I am designing a new database via a new sql file. I am using Oracle SQL Developer and logged in as sysdba.

I would like to know if SQL developer supports or has equivalent command to

```
connect scott/tiger;
```

Thank you in advance.

**Edit**

I am trying to create a foreign key on Schema A table referencing to Schema B table.

The error shown is

> [Err] ORA-00942: table or view does
>   not exist

I therefore want to login as "Schema B", grant all permission to SYS user, login as sys again and create the relationship.

Hope I am clearer this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the user SYS you should be able to create the relationship you want by simply prefixing object names with schema owner, as mentioned previously:

```
ALTR TABLE foo.t1 ADD FOREIGN KEY (col) REFERENCES bar.t2(ID);
```

That said, you must also grant the REFERENCES privilege to the user foo in order to make this relationship:

```
GRANT REFERENCES ON bar.t2 TO foo;
```

The user SYS should be able to do all this. Whether it's a good practice or not is another question.

Answer (score 5):

I believe you need to break and re-establish the connection to the database/service in order to log in as a different user in SQL Developer.

However, if you simply want to be in the `SCOTT` user's name space (so that `CREATE TABLE EMP...` is executed as `CREATE TABLE SCOTT.EMP ...`, you can issue

`alter session set current_schema = SCOTT;`

Comment: Being new to Oracle, I think I have a mistake in the concept itself. I have edited the question to the specific problem I have.

Answer (score 1):

Also remember that if you're trying to create a FK to a table in a different schema & there aren't any synonyms, you have to fully qualify the name:

eg, as the user SCHEMA_A:

```
ALTER TABLE SCHEMA_A.TABLE_A
add CONSTRAINT fk_TABLE_B
  FOREIGN KEY (COLUMN_A)
  REFERENCES SCHEMA_B.TABLE_B(COLUMN_B);
```

You mention use of the SYS user - I hope you're not logging in a SYS to do normal development...